# not replicating data to all client nodes

Tags: symmetricds

I want replication between three nodes and I am using symmetricds pro version 3.7.23.
Say I have nodes A,B and C. 
Say here A is master node and B,C are clients.
When I am inserting data on master node then data is moving to both nodes A and B.
When I am inserting data on node B then data is moving to master node but not to node C. When I am inserting data on node C then data is moving to master node but not to node B.
where am I wrong?

thanks in advance,
srikanth

Answer (score 1):

set the sync_on_incoming_batch as described here: http://www.symmetricds.org/doc/3.1/html/advanced-topics.html#bi-direction-sync